# Nested IF formula in excel returning "False"

Tags: excel, if-statement

My formula is returning the values I need, but my final return I want to be "0" if the person does not meet the criteria. Can someone take a look and tell me what I am missing?

=IF([Job Status]="FT",IF([Years Service]>=15,[Current Salary]*$T$3,IF([Years Service]<15,[Current Salary]*$T$4,IF([Job Status]="PT","0"))))

I have the "0" value at the end, but that obviously nor right.

Comment: you only provided 1 false result for the last IF you asked.  EVERY if will have a true case and a false case.  Since you did not provide a false result for you previous ifs, if the check turns out to be false, then FALSE is displayed by default when a fals option such as 0 has not been specified.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF([Job Status]="FT",IF([Years Service]>=15,[Current Salary]$T$3,[Current Salary]$T$4),IF([Job Status]="PT","0","JOB TYPE NOT FOUND"))
```

Try that out for size.  It will first check if you have an FT.  If you have an FT then it will check years of service for being greater than or equal to 15 and give T3.  If its not it means its less than 15 to it will return T4.  If the job is not FT it then checks to see if it a PT job.  IF it is PT it will return 0.  If it not PT, it will tell you that the Job Status has not been found.  meaning it not FT and its not PT.

IF your only criteria happen when the person is FT and all other results return 0, then you can replace the entire last if with 0.

```
=IF([Job Status]="FT",IF([Years Service]>=15,[Current Salary]$T$3,[Current Salary]$T$4),0)
```